# C# Json deserializing properties with changing names

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So I want to deserialize a Json reply that looks like this:

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) prices and volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "OMXS30",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-07-11 10:03:00",
    "4. Interval": "1min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (1min)": {
    "2018-07-11 10:03:00": {
        "1. open": "1526.9352",
        "2. high": "1526.9522",
        "3. low": "1526.6548",
        "4. close": "1526.7195",
        "5. volume": "0"
    },
    "2018-07-11 10:02:00": {
        "1. open": "1526.3879",
        "2. high": "1527.0217",
        "3. low": "1526.3879",
        "4. close": "1526.9825",
        "5. volume": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following classes:

```
class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Time Series (1min)")]
    public TimeSeries timeSeries { get; set; }
}

class Metadata
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string information { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public string lastRefreshed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. Interval")]
    public string interval { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. Output Size")]
    public string outputSize { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("6. Time Zone")]
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

class TimeSeries
{
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public List<DataValues> dataValues { get; set; }
}

class DataValues
{
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public float open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public float high { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public float low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public float close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public float volume { get; set; }
}
```

The deserialization of the metadata work, but  can't seem to get it to work for the datavalues that are in the timestamps. I think that is because the Json property name is changing with every timestamp.

What I want is the values of every timestamp to be in the list called dataValues.

I am using Newtonsoft.Json.

I am trying to get a value like this:

```
string result = root.timeSeries.dataValues[0].close.ToString();
```

The error that I get is: the object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Does `timeseries` deserialize correctly here?

Comment: @JayGould I am not sure. Alltough I've gotten rid of the error message that said that the deserializeation was wrong.

Comment: aren't you missing a level? looks like your TimeSeries should be a list of objects containing a Datetime object and a DataValues object.

Comment: @Hack OP actually has one too many level in their structure.  The `TimeSeries` class is not needed at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the "keys" of your object change and are not known ahead of time, the best structure for you to use is a `Dictionary<string, DataValues>` for your `timeSeries` property and ditch your `TimeSeries` class:

```
class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Time Series (1min)")]
    public Dictionary<string, DataValues> timeSeries { get; set; }
}

class Metadata
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string information { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public string lastRefreshed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. Interval")]
    public string interval { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. Output Size")]
    public string outputSize { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("6. Time Zone")]
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

class DataValues
{
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public float open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public float high { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public float low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public float close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public float volume { get; set; }
}
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UrGDZ4)